# can tableau server send out scheduled report to a email distribution list

Tags: tableau-api

I have to send out a daily report to a list of people in a email group.  can anyone help me understand if tableau have any power to schedule a report and send it to my distribution list ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Tableau Server does have features for sending notification emails when subscribed views have been refreshed. From Tableau's online help site, the article ["Set Up a Server for Subscriptions"](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/subscribe.htm) looks to cover the details of configuring the server for subscriptions, enabling them and managing them.

The article doesn't specify what version of Tableau server you need to do this, but we've had this feature where I work since version 10.1.

There's also [this Tableau community forum thread](https://community.tableau.com/thread/122893) discussing how to send out PDF reports, but this looks a bit more complicated.

EDIT: Tableau 2019.3 [adds native PDF subscriptions](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2019/10/new-pdf-feature-20193-supports-report-bursting-workflow).